# sending command and obtaining a reply from actionscript 3 / air

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am attempting to send a command to the command line with an air/as3 application.
I have seen some documentation on the invoke command but i am wondering if anyone else has dealt with the same set of circumstances.

basically the user will be checking boxes and filling out a form which will then be written as arguments to an application that will be doing the work. this application accepts these arguments as well as a place to store the output file and processes the file.

so is it possible to send commands to the command line using as3/air and furthermore is it possible to obtain the resulting message from the command line.

I have searched a bit for this sort of information but it seems that google returns a lot of 'how to compile as3 from the command line' tutorials and there are very few articles concerning air/as3 and it's possible interactions with the system's command line.

Thank you in advance, 
-Nathan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no way to launch apps from AIR (explanation [here](http://www.bitwisemag.com/2/Adobe-AIR-Going-Native-ish)), nor to send anything to the command line ... however mike chambers created [CommandProxy](http://code.google.com/p/commandproxy/) that allows you to do so, interfacing with a C# counterpart ...

greetz

back2dos

Answer (score 2):

AIR 2.0 has Native Process API. Through which now its possible.